# How to show full path of a file including the full filename in Mac OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line

**'ls'** can show the file name, e.g

```
ls config.inc.php
config.inc.php
```

**'pwd'** show current folder full path, e.g

```
pwd
/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin
```

Is there a command can put them together, would be able to show:

```
/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `realpath`

E.g.:

```
$ realpath README.md 
/Users/joe/my/long/directory/structure/README.md
```

Answered here on stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915075/441960

Make sure you download the coreutils on Homebrew as it isn't installed by default on all macs:

```
brew install coreutils
```

FYI, my version of MacOS (OSX):

```
$ uname -a
Darwin my-machine 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: `Darwin  23.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.3.0` seems to have `realpath` by default.

Answer (score 34):

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031502/804713

> macports and homebrew provide a coreutils package containing greadlink
>   (GNU readlink). credit to Michael Kallweitt post in mackb.com
>
> brew install coreutils
>
> greadlink -f file.txt

Comment: This was driving me nuts. I was thinking why `-f` wouldn't work on non-GNU and how to make it work. This works. Thanks

Comment: Note that this also works for directories

Answer (score 22):

There are many ways to do that; here is one example that may work for you:

```
claw:~ jonv$ echo `pwd`/`ls config.in.php`
/Users/jonv/config.in.php
```

If you want more examples, there are a bunch on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file) post at stackoverflow.

Comment: Most good answers on in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file don't work out of the box on OS X, however.

Answer (score 13):

In Mac OSX, do the following steps:

1. `cd` into the directory of the target file.
2. Type either of the following terminal commands.

Terminal

```
ls "`pwd`/file.txt"
echo $(pwd)/file.txt
```

3. Replace `file.txt` with your actual file name.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the "find" command for listing all files with complete path:

```
find DirectoryName -type f
```

or just the following:

```
find . -type f
```

Comment: This does not return the absolute path (which seems to be what OP was looking for)

Comment: Only shows the absolute path if you are not in the same directory as the file/directory you are targeting

Answer (score 6):

Didn't like any of the given solutions so I made up my own based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22684652/953327

Create alias which simply is a function call that combines `pwd` and `ls $1`. You can then add this to your `.bash_profile` if you choose.

```
alias lsf='function _lsf(){ echo "$(pwd)/$(ls $1)"; };_lsf'
```

Example of use:

```
lsf registry.lock
-> /tmp/registry.lock
```

I chose `lsf` for "list full" or "list file", makes sense to me but feel free to modify.

---

**Update (Thanks @santiago-arizti)** To be able to use this with relative paths (e.g. `lsf ../../readme.md`)

```
alias lsf='function _lsf(){ (cd $(dirname "$1") && echo $(pwd)/$(basename "$1")) };_lsf'
```

Comment: I needed to call i like this `lsf ../../readme.md` so I altered your version a little bit `alias lsf='function _lsf(){ (cd $(dirname "$1") && echo $(pwd)/$(basename "$1")) };_lsf'`

Comment: hope you don't mind, I added my own answer but with a script in a $PATH dir instead of an aliase

Answer (score 3):

The following will find a file within the working directory that matches `file.txt` and return its absolute path

```
find `pwd` -name file.txt
```

Comment: Perfect. 654321

Answer (score 2):

I wanted more than you needed, I needed to be able also to ask about files in a relative directory, like `../../readme.md`, and the result should be something like `/Users/santi/readme.md`

So I created a (executable) script in a folder that is part of the `$PATH` called `lsf` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
F=${1:?'usage lsf ../../readme.md'}
( cd $(dirname "$F") && echo $(pwd)/$(basename "$F") )
```

So you can use it like this:

```
santi@santis-mac:~/p/dir1/dir2$ lsf ../../readme.md 
/Users/santi/p/readme.md
```

No parameters gives you warning

```
santi@santis-mac:~/p/dir1/dir2$ lsf
/Users/santi/bin/lsf: line 3: 1: usage lsf ../../readme.md
```

Fake directory gives you warning (because of `dirname`)

```
santi@santis-mac:~/p/dir1/dir2$ lsf ../../fakedir/readme.md
/Users/santi/bin/lsf: line 5: cd: ../../fakedir: No such file or directory
```

Fake file but real directory doesn't warn (you can add validation if you need)

```
santi@santis-mac:~/p/dir1/dir2$ lsf ../../fakefile.md 
/Users/santi/p/fakefile.md
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a solution that wouldn't require me to type out the name of my target file, so I added this to my `~./bash_profile` file:

```bash
alias lsa="ls|xargs printf \"$(pwd)/%s\n\" *"
```

Now, when I run `lsa` in the terminal, I get an output like this:

[image]

If I *really* need just one file, I just grep it like `lsa|grep Filename`. I guess there are more advanced solutions with their own advantages, but this is good enough for me.